# Placing a float after a \paragraph heading

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I am composing a document, in which I have a heading followed by a table and that repeats every time. There is no other text. I have been trying to achieve that with the `\paragraph` heading, however I am having trouble positioning the table float to appear after the heading even with the `[H]` option from the float package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Paragraph 1}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\paragraph{Paragraph 2} 

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result (the paragraph headings appear after the tables):

[image]

If the paragraph is not empty, then I get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Paragraph 1} text 1

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\paragraph{Paragraph 2} text 2

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, if I use the `\subsubsection` or the `\subsubsection*` heading instead of the `\paragraph` heading I also get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Paragraph 1}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsubsection*{Paragraph 2}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to use the `\paragraph` heading with a float appearing after it and if yes, how could I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

**SOLUTION:**

As suggested by @UlrikeFischer in the comment, adding `~` after the paragraph heading solves the problem.

Comment: Why  don't you just use `tabular`? `table` floats and you don't want things to float, so you don't need it. Is that right?

Comment: make the paragraph "non-empty" by adding e.g. a space `~` . (run-in headings are a bit special).

Comment: @cicada Thank you for your suggestion. However some of the tables are actually `longtable`. In addition, if I strip the `table` environment, the tabular appears on the same line as the heading. I would need to use `~\\` in order to put it on the line below.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much, works like a charm!

Comment: with longtable you can also check https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/131